# xmllint: how to convert UTF-8 numeric references into characters

Tags: utf-8, xmllint

I'd like to convert UTF-8 numeric references into characters in the output from xmllint.

To reproduce:

```
$ wget http://il.srgssr.ch/integrationlayer/1.0/ue/rts/video/play/4727630.xml
$ xmllint --xpath "/Video/AssetMetadatas/AssetMetadata/title/text()" 4727630.xml && echo
Le jardin apprivois&#xE9; - Entre pierre et bois
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
Le jardin apprivoisé - Entre pierre et bois
```

I've read the man page and tried different options, but nothing worked.

If possible I'd like to achieve this using options from xmllint, or if this is not possible with another command line tool which is commonly found in Linux distributions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I understand that the question is a little bit outdated by I came here from Google and want to share possible answer for future visitors.
It is necessary to slightly change xpath expression and use string() function instead of text():

```
$ wget http://il.srgssr.ch/integrationlayer/1.0/ue/rts/video/play/4727630.xml
$ xmllint --xpath "string(/Video/AssetMetadatas/AssetMetadata/title)" 4727630.xml
Le jardin apprivoisé - Entre pierre et bois
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very useful!

Comment: Awesome, that solve my problem, too, which already caused me some headache! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way which I think can completely solves this problem. The trick is using the `recode` library provided by GNU to change output encoding from `html` to `utf8`.

```
$ wget http://il.srgssr.ch/integrationlayer/1.0/ue/rts/video/play/4727630.xml
$ xmllint --xpath "/Video/AssetMetadatas/AssetMetadata/title/text()" 4727630.xml | recode html..utf8
Le jardin apprivoisé - Entre pierre et bois
```

`recode` can be installed using `apt-get install recode`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `xmllint` against non-valid HTML5 chunks, where I don't have `charset` attribute declared in `head`. So, I'm using `cat` to add on-the-fly only necessary line to make `xmllint` happy with UTF8 input and output it as UTF8 correctly:

```
echo '<meta charset="utf8">' | cat - fileWriteInUTF8.chunk | \
     xmllint --html --xpath 'string(//video/source/@src)' 2>/dev/null -
```

**HTML5 content in fileWriteInUTF8.chunk:**

```
<video>
 <source src="/path/to/content_with_accent-éàü.mp4">
</video>
```

**Output after `cat`:**

```
<meta charset="utf8">
<video>
 <source src="/path/to/content-with_accent-éàü.mp4">
</video>
```

*I'm using `2>/dev/null` to drop HTML invalid warning message, use it with care!*

I know it's an uggly solution, but I don't find better actually.

Answer (score -2):

How about good old sed and echo?

```
$ wget http://il.srgssr.ch/integrationlayer/1.0/ue/rts/video/play/4727630.xml
$ echo -e $(xmllint --xpath "/Video/AssetMetadatas/AssetMetadata/title/text()" 4727630.xml | sed -e 's/&#x/\\u/g' -e 's/;//g')
Le jardin apprivoisé - Entre pierre et bois
```

Comment: You are providing an imperfect solution to a question asked 6.4 years ago which had a decent answer provided 5 years ago.  It is unclear how your solution improves on the previous solution. Augmenting your answer with an explanation for why it is better than the previous answer would be useful.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.